# Compare month and year in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying this:

```
select * from venda where to_char(data_venda, 'MM-YYYY') = '07/2017'
```

Nothing returns.

The database does have two records with this date:

> '21/07/2017'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the same separator:

```
select v.*
from venda v
where to_char(v.data_venda, 'MM-YYYY') = '07-2017';
```

There are other ways to write this that don't involve changing data types:

```
where date_trunc('month', v.data_venda) = '2017-07-01'
where v.data_venda >= '2017-07-01' and v_data_venda < '2017-08-01'
```

The latter is nice, because it can readily use an index.